# How do I upgrade CiviCRM on a local site that I installed with buildkit civibuild?

Tags: upgrade, civicrm-buildkit, civibuild

A while back I did

```
$ civibuild create demo.local --type drupal-demo --url http://demo.local
```

and got a working local site running CiviCRM 4.7.9. **Great.**

---

Now I'd like to upgrade this site to 4.7.17.

I tried:

```
$ cd ~/buildkit/build/demo.local/sites/all/modules/civicrm
$ git fetch
$ git checkout 4.7.17
$ cv flush
$ drush civicrm-upgrade-db
```

The last command gives `You are already upgraded to CiviCRM 4.7.9`.

What did I miss?

EDIT:

Also I have tried:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git pull
```

as well as browsing to `http://demo.local/civicrm/upgrade?reset=1` to perform the database upgrades *(Which tells me "Your database has already been upgraded to CiviCRM 4.7.9")*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### tldr

```
cd buildkit/build/dmaster/sites/all/modules/civicrm

## Ensure that all your stuff is clean/committed.
git scan status

## Update git repos. Choose ONE of:
git scan up
./bin/givi checkout X.Y.Z

## Regenerate data. Choose ONE of:
civibuild reinstall dmaster
./bin/setup.sh -Dg && drush civicrm-upgrade-db
```

### Checking the git repos

There are multiple git repos in your build (`civicrm-core.git`, `civicrm-packages.git`, etal). Before making a major switch, I first double-check that all of these repos are in sane condition -- ie there shouldn't be any uncommitted changes, the repos should be on normal branches, etc.

```
git scan status
```

### Updating the git repos

As a developer who tracks mainline branches, my day-to-day interest is "updating to the latest revision of `master` or `4.6`". The command `git scan up` will perform a standard "fast-forward merge" (`git pull --ff-only`) across all the repos:

```
git scan up
```

(Tip: If you didn't cleanup earlier, then "fast-forward" may not be possible. It takes some judgment to decide what to do -- e.g. a "merge" versus "rebase". Rather than risk a wrong decision, `git scan` will skip these repos and display warnings instead.)

Your example uses a tag. Hopping among tags is a bit different than tracking a branch. For this, I use `givi`:

```
./bin/givi checkout 4.7.17
```

### Updating the generated code, config files, databases

As a developer who does weird things on a day-to-day basis (like manually hacking SQL records to provoke weird situations), I have trouble remembering all the weird things that I've done before -- and honestly don't care about them afterward. I just want to get back to a consistent/clean state. Reinstalling is nice because it recreates/overwrites all generated-code, config-files, and database content.

```
civibuild reinstall dmaster
```

However, that does reset all the data. If you care about the content in the database, then don't do a reinstall. Instead, update the generated-code and perform a DB upgrade:

```
./bin/setup.sh -Dg
drush civicrm-upgrade-db
```

### See also

For more discussion, see the blog post: https://civicrm.org/blogs/totten/developer-tip-managing-multiple-git-repositories

Comment: This documentation was migrated to: https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/tools/civibuild/#upgrade-site

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I don't think that git checkout would overwrite files without doing a git pull, would it? Those files need to be overwritten with the new version.

The next thing is that you probably need to visit the upgrade URL:

http:///civicrm/upgrade?reset=1

Good luck!

Comment: That didn't do it for me. (Updated my question for clarification)

Answer (score 0):

Second try: do a git checkout  -f

To force overwrite of local files!